# Header slider not working on iphone

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, header, slider

I have been trying to fix this for over a week but I can´t seem to find any possible solution.

I have a slider in the header of my website that works on every device but iPhone. The site live is www.gewexhibition.com

The crazy thing is that it was working a few weeks ago and now it just stopped working on iPhones. I can only think that the problem might be that the script has some issues with the navigation menu but I have no clue how to fix this.

Can anybody give me some pointers to discover the problem?

These are the links to the slider script and the navigation menu, both with jquery.

http://gewexhibition.com/js/jquery.anyslider.js
http://gewexhibition.com/js/jquery.nav.js

Also, this is te code I have for the slider in the html:

```
            <div class="top" id="top">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="one">
                    <h1>Programming & Designing</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="two">
                    <h1>Retail Marketing<br>& Sales</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="three">
                    <h1>Installation & logistics</h1>
                </div>
            </div><!-- slider -->
        </div><!-- top-->
```

Comment: `Can anybody give me some pointers to discover the problem?` Yes if you show your code. Maybe some libraries, just something.

Comment: I just did. Sorry @DOCTYPEHTML

Comment: Your linked JS links where minifyed, can you share a debug-file?

Comment: I just did it. They are not minified no more. They are the same links.@DOCTYPEHTML